# <pre> versus four-space indentation?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, pre

I frequently make answers with code samples that are surrounded with `pre` tags instead of having each line indented with an extra four spaces, because doing the latter either means I have to add four spaces each line, or go into gedit, change the tab settings to four-spaced tabs, then type away, then indent. I'm a little too lazy to do that sometimes.

My question is, as most of the time when I do this, someone quickly swoops in and changes it to four-spaced indents to invoke code mode. Why is this? Is there a benefit to that method? Is there a rule against `pre` tags?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you can just select the lines you want and press ctrl+k (or click the code-sample button) and it'll do the indent for you...

IIRC there are *some* things that the `<pre>` doesn't like, but I can't think of them off the top of my head. Indented is *generally* easier to work with, IMO.

Comment: +1 -- in additon, `<pre>` content doesn't get code highlighting, which is probably the reason why people prefere four-space-indent

Comment: +1 for Ctr-k. Didn't know about that. I've been indenting in my editor.

Comment: Thanks! A great tip there, and now I know that the indented code block has syntax highlighting and automatically escapes special HTML characters.

Answer (score 7):

I use the 4 white spaces for code blocks (and the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> shortcut) when I want syntax highlighting.

I use `<pre>` when I want *pre-formatted text* without syntax highlighting (e.g. for console output).

I sometimes use `<pre><code>` when I want *pre-formatted text* for *code* with syntax highlighting **and** more advanced formatting options, like bold and italic, for special emphasis:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("you can't do that with 4 spaces");
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that it appears that [`<!-- language: lang-none -->`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78363/manually-specify-language-for-syntax-highlighting/81971#81971) is [apparently now the preferred mechanism](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85379/formatting-preview-is-not-accurate-for-code-blocks-in-numbered-lists/85410#85410) for preformatted text without syntax highlighting. Note also that syntax highlighting on `<pre><code>` no longer works automatically when a language is not detected.

Answer (score 5):

Well, if my code actually involves HTML/XML, then this will most certainly not work.

```
My code!
Hello world!
Nop!
```

**versus**

```
<pre>Arrge!</pre>
<div>Hello world!</div>
<p>Nop!</p>
```

Of course you would could to rewrite all that angular brackets diligently as `&gt;` and `&lt;`, but that's just a waste of time...

Answer (score 4):

Semantically, `<pre>` is for [**pre**-formatted text](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.4), not [code](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.2.1): it's to make sure whitespace is preserved and little else.

As others have pointed out, syntax highlighting is only invoked on code blocks, so consider it a gift that others are taking the time to fix your mistake and properly enclose the code with the correct markup.